# Genemu JQueryColor Field Symfony2 error ColorPicker

Tags: symfony

I try to use Genemu JQueryColor Field with Symfony2

```
    <?php
// ...
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        // ...
        ->add('color', 'genemu_jquerycolor')
        ->add('colorpicker', 'genemu_jquerycolor', array(
            'widget' => 'image'
    ))
}
```

It runs Exception

> Neither the property "colorpicker" nor one of the methods
>   "getColorpicker()", "colorpicker()", "isColorpicker()",
>   "hasColorpicker()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class
>   "KALAN\NetRDVBundle\Entity\Station

I try just

```
->add('colorpicker', 'genemu_jquerycolor', array(
                'widget' => 'image'
        ))
```

No error, but just inpput text with code color

I try

```
->add('color', 'genemu_jquerycolor', array(
            'widget' => 'image'))
```

No error, the background color is ok but i can change the color.

I try just

```
->add('colorpicker', 'genemu_jquerycolor', array(
            'widget' => 'image'))
```

Or

```
->add('colorpicker', 'genemu_jquerycolor')
```

The error is the same

> Neither the property "colorpicker" nor one of the methods
>   "getColorpicker()", "colorpicker()", "isColorpicker()",
>   "hasColorpicker()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class
>   "KALAN\NetRDVBundle\Entity\Station".

Even if i can't add

```
{{ form_widget(form.colorpicker) }}
```

Comment: show us your entity 'KALAN\NetRDVBundle\Entity\Statio'

Comment: Your error tells it all. Your entity *"Satio"* does not have the required methods. Try adding methods `getColorpicker` and `setColorpicker` or just the property `colorpicker` to your entity.

Comment: Exact, i don't have colorpicker but color property in entity. I need the both?    `->add('color', 'genemu_jquerycolor', array( 'widget' => 'image'))` set the backcolor but not button or other to change it. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how i can use this Bundle... I try to find another...

Comment: Hi, I have exactly  the same problem, did you found a solution or another bundle with a better documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

May be its late maybe its not , the thing is like this.
Your class doesnt have the property  **colorpicker** .

When you add a field to the builder , the builder will try to map it to the field of the entity you are making the formType for (in this case Station).

What you need to do is tell to the builder not to map that field. You can achieve this using the "mapped" property.
 http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped  ------>Form type doc.